# AS3 vertical shooter: Mouse click not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouse

I'm just trying to make a simple vertical shooter, one where the player's ship is controlled by the mouse and fires a laser when you click the mouse. However, when I try running the code, I keep getting the same error message:

"1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent."

The thing is, I declared the MouseEvent. I know I did. It is as follows:

--==--

```
package
```

{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.utils.Timer;

import flash.events.TimerEvent;

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
public class SpaceShooter_II extends MovieClip //The public class extends the class to a movie clip.
{   
    public var army:Array; //the Enemies will be part of this array.
    ///*
    //Laser Shots and Mouse clicks:
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public var playerShot:Array; //the player's laser shots will fill this array.
    public var mouseClick:Boolean;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseGoDown);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseGoUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onTick);
    //*/
    //Back to the rest of the code:
    public var playerShip:PlayerShip; //This establishes a variable connected to the PlayerShip AS.
    public var onScreen:GameScreen; //This establishes a variable that's connected to the GameScreen AS.
    public var gameTimer:Timer; //This establishes a new variable known as gameTimer, connected to the timer utility.

    ///*
    //Functions connected to Shooting via mouse-clicks:
    public function mouseGoDown(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        mouseClick = true;
    }

    public function mouseGoUp(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        mouseClick = false;
    }
    //*/

    //This function contains the bulk of the game's components.
    public function SpaceShooter_II() 
    {
        //This initiates the GameScreen.
        onScreen = new GameScreen;
        addChild ( onScreen );

        //This sets up the enemy army.
        army = new Array(); //sets the "army" as a NEW instance of array.
        var newEnemy = new Enemy( 100, -15); //This will create new enemies. There's new var newEnemy statement, hence we call THIS a var.
        army.push ( newEnemy ); //the new enemy is added to the army.
        addChild( newEnemy ); //the new enemy is added to the game.

        //This sets up the player's avatar, a spaceship.
        playerShip = new PlayerShip(); //This invokes a new instance of the PlayerShip... 
        addChild( playerShip ); //...And this adds it to the game.
        playerShip.x = mouseX; //These two variables place the "playerShip" on-screen...
        playerShip.y = mouseY; //...at the position of the mouse.

        ///*
        //This sets up the player's laser shots:
        playerShot = new Array(); //sets the "army" as a NEW instance of array.
        var goodShot = new goodLaser( playerShip.x, playerShip.y); //This will create new enemies. There's new var newEnemy statement, hence we call THIS a var.
        playerShot.push ( goodShot ); //the new enemy is added to the army.
        addChild( goodShot ); //the new enemy is added to the game.
        //*/

        //This sets up the gameTimer, where a lot of the action takes place.
        gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
        gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick );
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    //This function contains the things that happen during the game (player movement, enemy swarms, etc.)
    public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void
    {
        //This "if" statement is where the array that contains the enemy ships is initialized.
        if ( Math.random() < 0.05 ) //This sets the number of ships showing up at once.
        {
            var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 800 //Generates a random number between 0 and 1.
            var newEnemy:Enemy = new Enemy ( randomX, -15 ); //This shows where the enemy starts out--at a random position on the X plane, but at a certain points on the Y plane.
            army.push( newEnemy ); //This adds the new enemy to the "army" Array.
            addChild( newEnemy ); //This makes the new enemy part of the game.
        }

        //This "for" statement sends the enemies downward on the screen.
        for each (var enemy:Enemy in army) //Every time an enemy is added to the "army" array, it's sent downward.
        {
            enemy.moveDown(); //This is the part that sends the enemy downward.

            //And now for the collision part--the part that establishes what happens if the enemy hits the player's spaceship:
            if ( playerShip.hitTestObject ( enemy ) ) //If the playerShip makes contact with the enemy...
            {
                gameTimer.stop(); //This stops the game.
                dispatchEvent( new PlayerEvent(PlayerEvent.BOOM) ); //This triggers the game over screen in the PlayerEvent AS

            }
        }

        //This, incidentally, is the player's movement controls:
        playerShip.x = mouseX;
        playerShip.y = mouseY;

        ///*
        //And this SHOULD  be the shooting controls, if the mouse function would WORK...
        if ( mouseClick = true )
        {
            var goodShot = new goodLaser( playerShip.x, playerShip.y); //This will create new lasers. There's new variable in the statement, hence we call THIS a variable.
            playerShot.push ( goodShot ); //the new laser is added to the army.
            addChild( goodShot ); //the new laser is added to the game.
        }

        for each (var goodlaser: goodLaser in goodShot)
        {
            goodlaser.beamGood();
        }
        //*/
    }

}
```

}

--==--

Sorry if the brackets are coming in uneven, I just wanted to outline the code in its entirety, and show the parts I added where things started going wrong, so someone can tell me what I need to do to make this work.

Basically, everything else works...but when I work on the things connected to the mouse clicking and the array with the lasers, the program stops working. The error seems to be connected to the functions "mouseGoUp" and "mouseGoDown," but I'm not sure how to fix that.

This assignment is due March 8. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add this    `import flash.events.MouseEvent`;    to the top of your class and it should work. You need to import everything you use. That's why you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

As well as importing MouseEvent, in the initialisation of your game, you should add event listeners to the stage which listen for the MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP events:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseGoDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseGoUp);
```

What would be simpler, though, would be to do away with the 'mouseClick' variable and have just a single MouseEvent listener which listens for the MOUSE_DOWN event and trigger your missle launch from the handler.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help. I added import flash.events.MouseEvent, and altered the "addEventListender" for the "MouseEvents" to have "stage." at the beginning...

Comment: ...And now I'm getting a whole new slew of errors:

Line 15 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
Line 15 1120: Access of undefined property mouseGoDown.
Line 16 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
Line 16 1120: Access of undefined property mouseGoUp.
Line 17 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
Line 17 1120: Access of undefined property Event.
Line 17 1120: Access of undefined property onTick.

Comment: I thought I defined these properties. What am I supposed to do...?

Comment: If you are getting an 'undefined property stage' error, most likely the object triggering it isn't on the Stage. Where (and in which Class) have you added the MouseEvent listener? Are the 'mouseGoDown' and 'mouseGoUp' handler functions in the same Class as the listeners which call them? There will be some reason Flash isn't able to find them - even if it's just a typo.

Comment: If you refer to the code that I've provided at the top, that's my current setup of the code in my main ActionScript "class." Inside the "SpaceShooter_II" class are the MouseEvent listeners for the mouse button being clicked. The "mouseGoUp" and "mouseGoDown" functions are in the same class, and they give a value to the boolean mouseClick. However, inside the "onTick" function is where the onClick variable is supposed to be acknowledged. Do I have to make a separate variable in there to connect to "onClick," or something?

Comment: You should add the event listeners INSIDE your Class constructor (the public function named 'SpaceShooter_II'). Also you will not need an alternative version of 'onClick' as a Class has access to any variables declared outside of functions, throughout the Class. Variables declared INSIDE functions have a scope limited to that function.

Answer (score 0):

I had a game like this if you want the entire source i can give it to you but the main parts are

```
var delayCounter:int = 0;
var mousePressed:Boolean = false;
var delayMax:int = 5;//How rapid the fire is
var playerSpeed:int = 5;
var bulletList:Array = [];
var bullet:Bullet;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownHandler,false,0,true);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUpHandler,false,0,true);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop,false,0,true);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    player.rotation = Math.atan2(mouseY - player.y,mouseX - player.x) * 180 / Math.PI + 90;

    if (bulletList.length > 0)
    {
        for each (bullet in bulletList)
        {
            bullet.bulletLoop();
        }
    }
    if (mousePressed)
    {
        delayCounter++;
        if ((delayCounter == delayMax))
        {
            shootBullet();
            delayCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    if (upPressed)
    {
        player.y -=  playerSpeed;

    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        player.y +=  playerSpeed;

    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        player.x -=  playerSpeed;

    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        player.x +=  playerSpeed;

    }
}

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mousePressed = true;
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mousePressed = false;
}

function shootBullet():void
{
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(stage,player.x,player.y,player.rotation - 90);
bulletList.push(bullet);
stage.addChildAt(bullet,1);
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if (event.keyCode == 87)
{
    upPressed = true;
}
if (event.keyCode == 83)
{
    downPressed = true;
}
if (event.keyCode == 65)
{
    leftPressed = true;
}
if (event.keyCode == 68)
{
    rightPressed = true;
}
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if (event.keyCode == 87)
{
    upPressed = false;
}
if (event.keyCode == 83)
{
    downPressed = false;
}
if (event.keyCode == 65)
{
    leftPressed = false;
}
if (event.keyCode == 68)
{
    rightPressed = false;
}

}
```

BULLET CLASS

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip
{
    private var stageRef:Stage;
    private var speed:Number = 10;//speed that the bullet will travel at
    private var xVel:Number = 5;
    private var yVel:Number = 5;
    private var rotationInRadians = 0;


    public function Bullet(stageRef:Stage, X:int, Y:int, rotationInDegrees:Number):void
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        this.rotation = rotationInDegrees;
        this.rotationInRadians = rotationInDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    public function bulletLoop():void
    {
        xVel = Math.cos(rotationInRadians) * speed;
        yVel = Math.sin(rotationInRadians) * speed;
        x +=  xVel;
        y +=  yVel;
        if (x > stageRef.stageWidth || x < 0 || y > stageRef.stageHeight || y < 0)
        {
            deleteBullet();
        }
    }
    public function deleteBullet()
    {
        this.visible=false
        this.x=9999
        this.y=9999
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did everything for the main function go inside a class, or did you not include one in the main document?

Comment: That was on the timeline, wouldn't be hard to convert though